# Export two Sql result sets into Single excel file and send mail as an attachment

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I have 2 `Execute Sql task` result sets and I want to export into one Excel File with respective worksheets `Sheet1, Sheet2` with rename as respective Table Name and sent it to user as an attachment.

I want to design a SSIS package with `Execute Sql task` and `Script task`.

Please anyone can help me out on this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Execute SQL tasks to populate object-type variables with the results.

Then add a Script Task that loops through the object variables and populates your Excel sheets.  Save the sheets in an Excel file, and keep the path/name of the file in a variable.

Then add a send mail task and use the variable to find your Excel sheet and add it as an attachment.